# Symfony2 - Load user with own repository (FOSUser)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Currently, when symfony load my user on each page, It load the User only, but my User entity have relations with others entities (like a profile_picture attribute, which is an "Image" instance.

On each page, I have at least 2 queries to databse, one to etuser, the other to get the image, But with a personnal query, in my userRepository, I can do the same thing with 1 query (with a join).

How set symfony configuration to load users with my own repository function on each page ?

I'm using FOSUserBundle

Thanks :)

Comment: Check the docs to see how to plugin your own user provider.  That will allow customizing the query like you did in the repository.

Comment: Namely http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: In fact, you can extend the provider of FOSuserbundle. They are in the security folder.

Comment: Thanks, I've find the solution with your indications :D